# how to align a text in center of the window by using xft fonts in x11

Tags: c++, c, x11

I need to align a text in X11 windows in X11 application.
The alignment must be depended on window size, font size and string length.
Thanks in advance:)

I would like to use the concept of cell padding in x11 windows. I am using xft fonts for text. I used ascent, descent for aligning it vertically. Now I would like to have some help to align it horizontally (left, center, right and justify) like in MSWord.

[Example for horizontal+vertical spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbDDN.png)

I guess, now everyone can understand my need.

[I need the text with cell padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8xF3.png)

```
XftTextExtents8(display, fontXft, (XftChar8 *)textStr, strlen(textStr),&extents); 
fontWidth = extents.width -extents.x; 
singleFontHeight = fontXft->ascent - fontXft->descent;
if(vAlign == TOP_ALIGN)
   textY = singleFontHeight; 
else if(vAlign == CENTER_ALIGN) 
   textY = ((heightWin - fontHeight)/2 + singleFontHeight); 
else
   textY = heightWin;

if(hAlign == CENTER_ALIGN) 
    textX = (widthWin - fontWidth)/3;
else if(hAlign == RIGHT_ALIGN)
    textX = widthWin - fontWidth;
else 
    textX = 0;
```

Comment: You mean by using something like the [`XftTextExtents*`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/Xft.3.html#toc7) functions?

Comment: Yes, I need the code for that.

Comment: So, when you read the documentation I linked, and searched for related tutorials, and made some minimum effort to understand them - where did you get stuck?

Comment: Already am using XftTextExtents, but I want code for left, right and center alignment both horizontally and vertically
Also if I want 2 lines of text to be shown in one small window, what should I do?

Comment: Here is a sample on which am working,
XftTextExtents8( display, fontXft, (XftChar8 *)textStr, strlen(textStr),&extents );
fontWidth = extents.width -extents.x;
singleFontHeight  = fontXft->ascent - fontXft->descent;
if( vAlign == TOP_ALIGN )
 textY = singleFontHeight;
else if( vAlign == CENTER_ALIGN )
 textY = ((heightWin - fontHeight)/2 + singleFontHeight);
else
 textY = heightWin;

if( hAlign == CENTER_ALIGN )
 textX = (widthWin - fontWidth)/3;
else if( hAlign == RIGHT_ALIGN )
 textX = widthWin - fontWidth;
else
 textX = 0;

but this is not working for all situations

Comment: What situations does it work for? When does it fail, and how? I think this is a new question in its own right if you can't edit the existing one

Comment: Ok, Let me explain little more in detail. The alignment is something that we usually do in MSWord(Left, Center,Right,Justify). I want this concept for x11 windows. When I used ascent or decent, it is not fittings for each every window. Also I don't want to align each window individually, instead use same function or condition. Am I clear now?

Comment: No, I still have no idea what you're asking, what you've tried, how that failed, what the inputs are, what the outputs should be, what outputs you actually get or what your code looks like. How can anyone help with something so vague? Take a look at the help center, there is useful advice on how to ask a question that is actually answerable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least one error in your code which is that you take the height of the glyph as being (ascent - descent) when both are in fact positive numbers, so the total height should be (ascent + descent).

Also I don't see why for centre justification you are using (window width - string width) /3, unless you want some padding on the right hand side.